Romance/Drama movie from late 80' or early 90's
I saw this movie on one of the cable movie stations (the 3 provided back in the day when cable first arrived: Cinemax, Showtime or HBO) and it was either late 80's or early 90's.
An overweight gal was trying to lose weight and failing. She decided to post a personal ad for love and someone responded (an overweight man with the same issues).  When they set up the date they both sent their 'fit' friends in their place and things became a mess.  They ended up confessing to the truth and meeting their true selves and loving each other as is.
I believe the opening scene is with the gal driving and a car of guys flirting with her from their Jeep and once they came to a stop one of the guys got out and came to the car, but when he saw she was overweight he went back to the jeep and they sped off.

Was this a made for TV movie or "big" screen movie? Was it also released in the time frame you saw it, or was it shown then (meaning it might have been an older film)? Do you remember any of the actor/actresses? Any memorable lines or catchphrase? Do you know which of the "companies" released it? Trying to gather more spot points to help narrow the field.

Not sure if it was a made for TV or big screen or went straight to cable I think their were credits rolling at the end; I just remember watching it on cable and there wasn't much choice for channels back then.  It seemed to be in the 80's - 90's time frame from the hairstyles and clothes I can remember.  unfortunately I don't remember any actors but the main gal was pretty with dark long hair and the main guy had dark hair also.  I believe the 'friends' were blond, very fit and attractive.  I remember the main people were mad because the end of the date ended in the bedroom.

Also at the end of the movie the main people did get married and they showed signature or phase of something in cursive across the screen which could have been the name of the movie but not sure on that either.

Hopefully that will be enough for someone to recognize it, unfortunately for the moment, I'm not having luck.
